# Using LAStools in QGIS gives "global name 'os' is not defined"?

Tags: qgis, error, lidar, qgis-2.6, lastools

I have a problem with LAStools in QGIS 2.6.1. I have never used QGIS to process LiDAR data before.

I downloaded LAStools yesterday from the [rapidlasso GmbH](http://rapidlasso.com/2013/09/29/how-to-install-lastools-toolbox-in-qgis/) website. I unzipped the “lastools.zip” file into my osgeo folder (C:\OSGeo4W64\LAStools) and followed the instructions for activating LAStools and specifying the folder location. LAStools appears correctly in my Processing Toolbox in QGIS.

Then, I downloaded a LiDAR tile from the [National Land Survey of Finland](https://tiedostopalvelu.maanmittauslaitos.fi/tp/kartta?lang=en) as a .laz file. I tried to use lasground to view this data, and followed the instructions on the rapidlasso GmbH website (see screengrab). However, I get this message in my log:

> Algorithm lasground starting...global name 'os' is not defined See log for more details

Am I missing some dependency from my library?

[image]

Comment: QGIS 2.6 should already come with LiDAR tools installed, you just have to set the provider for the lastools folder within your QGIS directory. For example, mine is **C:\Program Files\QGIS Brighton\apps\qgis\python\plugins\processing\algs\lidar\lastools**.

Comment: Thanks Joseph. You were right about the LiDAR tools. I found them in the same folder location. I changed the folder location for the LAStools folder in Processing>Options>Providers>Tools for LiDAR data. I'm afraid I'm getting the same message though.

Comment: Hmm seems a few other people also have this problem (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/lastools/ktyrnfDjrQ4). I never used LiDAR so cannot provide much assistance but when I try to run it on a sample .las file, nothing happens. Hopefully others will advise.

Comment: Thanks Andre. I looked into that and, according to the rapidlasso GmbH website instructions, LAStools should be able to open .laz files. I'm no expert but I assume LAStools incorporates LASzip. Now I'm just wondering whether I'm missing something from the LAStools folder for decompressing .laz.

Comment: Thanks again Andre. I took your advice and tried to open a .las file downloaded from the Pennsylvania Spatial Data site (ftp://pamap.pasda.psu.edu/pamap_lidar/cycle1/LAS/North/2006/20000000/). No joy I'm afraid. Still the same message.

Answer (score 2):

My problem was that there was a space in the path to the .las file I was using.

Comment: We want longer answers. If you had the same problem consider expanding the answer. perhaps even screen shots showing both the broken and the cure.

Answer (score 1):

I followed the instructions contained within the README.txt file of the lastools newest version, a zip file downloadable from this link: http://lastools.org/download/lastools.zip.
Extract the zip file to any folder without spaces in the path. Open the QGIS_toolbox folder where you find the README.txt file. Open this file and follow the instructions from the line number 24.
I have QGIS 2.6.1 installed on Window 7 and lastools work well. For now I tried only the lasview algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

I have also been headbanging and have at least a partial solution. On a Mac, Go to Processing and then Options but DO NOT CLICK on activate. Click (or perhaps right click) on the white space on the right side of the folder icon, hit the right 3 dot button on the right side, then go to applications and select QGIS.

THEN hit the activate button.

I can then get a LASTools project to open with an input menu that I have not yet tried, but those steps do away with the "LASTools folder is not configured" that one gets otherwise. I either clicked or right clicked on the LASTools project in the window to activate the initiation window.