# wine + LAStools in QGIS 2.8.1, Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: qgis, ubuntu, lidar, lastools

I can't get wine + LAStools to work in QGIS 2.8.1 (ubuntu 14.04). I only get the 22 open source functions that comes with QGIS. Outside qgis wine + LAStools works fine.

My guess is that I am not specifying the folders correctly under Processing Options -> Tools for LiDAR data, and I can't find any documentation about it. You can enter the LAStools folder and the wine folder but it is not clear how this should be done. I looked at the source code for LAStoolsUtils.py where I believe this is partly handled. I think this line is important.

```
folder = wine_folder + "/wine " + lastools_folder
```

My LAStools folder can be found at:

```
/home/.../.wine/drive_c/LAStools/QGIS_toolbox/processing
```

So I put:

```
[wine folder] /home/.../

[LAStools folder] /drive_c/LAStools/QGIS_toolbox/processing
```

I thought /.wine could be the problem but changing /wine to /.wine did not help. I also tried all kinds of variation on the directory paths but nothing worked.

Any ideas how to get this to work? There are other questions like this but for windows/MAC. E.g.
[Using LAStools in QGIS gives "global name 'os' is not defined"?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/125116/problem-operating-lastools-in-qgis-2-6-1)

Comment: I don't think this is how Wine works... you would have to operate QGIS within WINE in order for the Windows-based application to use Windows-based files... that is to say, you can't just point QGIS on Ubuntu to the LASTools that Wine installed...

Comment: Thanks for input. So I need to run the windows version of QGIS (through wine)? But is there a "wine folder" option in the windows version? Seems odd but I havent tried the windows version. It was the wine folder option that made me think that you call wine within (ubuntu) QGIS.

Comment: Yes, run the windows version of QGIS through Wine and you should have no problem - your outputs should be useable by Ubuntu if you write them to a folder you can access via Ubuntu...

Comment: ok thanks. I think I will do the heavy LiDAR analyses with wine + LAStools outside QGIS.

Comment: sounds like a good plan... do report back, as I'd be interested to know how this worked and how the Wine component was implemented...!

Answer (score 4):

This is rapidlasso, creators of LAStools. It should be possible to configure QGIS such that a call to "WinE" is automatically prepended to each LAStools call. That is the idea behind providing an option to specify a "wine folder" ... you may ask in the LAStools user forum on google groups or see the comments of this [rapidlasso blog article](http://rapidlasso.com/2013/09/29/how-to-install-lastools-toolbox-in-qgis/).

---

The issue was finally solved. There was a bug in the processing scripts and therefore the mere presence of a path to the Wine folder did not - as intended - enable the use of Wine on non-Windows system. In the latest version of QGIS this should be fixed. For the discussion that led to finding this bug and a work-around for older QGIS versions see [this thread](http://rapidlasso.com/2013/09/29/how-to-install-lastools-toolbox-in-qgis/) in the [LAStools user forum](http://groups.google.com/group/lastools).

Comment: OK, this is good news (and in line with what I originally thought). I have posted a question on the google groups forum but no luck so far [https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/lastools/WSKtX1tbRTU]. I have also read the blog article in detail (comments too) and it does not provide much information about getting it to work in linux.

Comment: +1 Thank you for taking the time and effort to update your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem here. QGIS 2.8 has a problem to get the wine folder in (line 45 of the /foo/bar/.qgis2/python/plugins/processing/algs/lidar/lastools/LAStoolsUtils.py).

Changed this line to: wine_folder = '/usr/bin' (supposing that you've already installed wine)